# Creating a cloud storage bucket using AppEngine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Is there a way to create a bucket using AppEngine?

I've used `use google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageTools;` to write and read files but I have not been able to figure out how to create buckets.

**EDIT** I would not like to create the bucket manually, rather through code.

Comment: You can with the [Google APIs Client Library for PHP](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client)

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to read and write data using that library so I doubt I can figure that out @jterrace but thanks for the insight

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to create Google Cloud Storage buckets.

1) Create them from the new admin console - console.developers.google.com, click on "Storage" then "Cloud Storage". You should see the option of adding a bucket if you have billing enabled.

2) Use the default bucket. Go to appengine.google.com, click on "Application Settings", and you should see "Google Cloud Storage Bucket" listed. If you don't, then scroll to the bottom and click on "Create" under "Cloud Integration".

Please see this article for details - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/activate

===---===

For PHP reference on how to construct the proper API call:

https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Service/Storage.php

The API you want to call is here:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets/insert

So, basically, in your code, you want to generate a unique bucket name (because the namespace is universal to everyone, so simple bucket names are all taken). What some people do is append current date/time to the name of the bucket like (appID-date-time).

You want to make a bucket insert API call to create the bucket and then an object insert API call to put an object in the bucket. After which, you can manipulate the object by fetching it and modifying it.

Comment: I'd like to create it using PHP in the AppEngine

Comment: I made some edits, the implementation really depends on you.

The only advantage of creating a bucket programmatically is if you need a lot of different buckets with different ACLs. If you are just using it for simple storage, then manually create one bucket and upload all the object you need to that one bucket.

Comment: Thanks LiY, I appreciate the time it took to write this. It seems like most of this requires authorization (aka using `gsutil`). I was trying to see if there was a way to do this without authorization using PHP AppEngine but it doesn't seem like there is a straight forward way. I'll take a look at the `Storage.php`, but I'm not sure if you are able to use gsutil in the app engine.

Comment: If you create the bucket manually and set it to public access, you won't need to authenticate; otherwise you do because the bucket is private to the native app.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the cloud storage documentation for [examples](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/json-api-php-samples) of exercising their programmatic API, and the [appengine docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/appidentity/) for more information on authentication.

Comment: Thanks but there is nothing in these examples or documentations that have to do with creating buckets.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets/insert is the specific API call you'll want to adapt

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure your project is set up correctly and includes the Store APIs by [following the instructions here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/json-api-php-samples).

The following code will create a bucket a new bucket and then list all buckets associated with your project:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$projectId = "example"; // your app engine id (example.appspot.com).    
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials(); // This won't work locally.
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Storage::DEVSTORAGE_FULL_CONTROL);
$storage = new Google_Service_Storage($client);

// Create our new bucket.
$newBucket = new Google_Service_Storage_Bucket();
$newBucket->setName("test-bucket1");

try {
    $test = $storage->buckets->insert($projectId, $newBucket);
    print_r($test);
} catch (\Google_Service_Exception $e) {
    $error = $e->getErrors()[0];
    // Available: reason & message.
    die("Error message: ". $error["message"]);
}

// List all our buckets.
$buckets = $storage->buckets->listBuckets($projectId);

foreach ($buckets['items'] as $bucket) {
    printf("%s<br>", $bucket->getName());
}
```

Please note that this example won't work locally and must be deployed to Google's servers. Also, bucket names need to be globally unique so try appending a random number or your project id to the bucket name.